# How to use whereIn filter multiple times in a query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this code to retrive data from firestore

```
querysnap = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection("datas")
                              .where("cat", whereIn: Cateogryarray )
                              .where("City", whereIn:Cityarray)
                              .snapshots();
```

Then I get this error.

> You cannot use 'whereIn' filters more than once.

How can I execute this query.

Answer (score 2):

As the Firestore documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2) says:

> You can use at most one `in`, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.

Since you're trying to use two `in` clauses in your query, Firestore gives an error.

The most common workaround is to run with one clause against the database (typically the one you expect to exclude most documents from the result), and perform the rest of the filtering in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to get individual snapshots for each parameter that would need the `in`clause.

Then once you have each of your snapshots, do an intersection of the lists. This will return the results where every record adheres to each individual filter.